# How to loop variable values to ignore them in a csv file unix?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting

I have this content in file.csv

`cat file.csv`

```
QUOTA,landscape=test,region=europe,limit=N2_CPUS quota=24.0,quota_used=0.0,quota_used_percent=0
QUOTA,landscape=test,region=europe,limit=COMMITTED_N2_CPUS quota=0.0,quota_used=0.0,quota_used_percent=0
QUOTA,landscape=test,region=europe,limit=COMMITTED_C2_CPUS quota=0.0,quota_used=0.0,quota_used_percent=0
QUOTA,landscape=test,region=europe,limit=RESERVATIONS quota=100.0,quota_used=0.0,quota_used_percent=0
```

I need to remove values which contain strings "RESERVATIONS" and "N2_CPUS" and the variables can be random

`variable=("RESERVATIONS","N2_CPUS")`

I am able to do when i use one value as variable using

`cat file.csv | grep -v $variable`

When there are more values in a variable, even loops are not working as expected. Could you please suggest?

Comment: `grep -v "RESERVATIONS" | grep -v "N2_CPUS` ? Where are "loops"? `not working as expected` - please be specific. What is expected in loops case and what happens in loops case and what doesn't match?

Answer (score 1):

I would use egrep (or grep -E, depending on your flavor of linux)
 `variable="RESERVATIONS|N2_CPUS"
cat file.csv | egrep -v $variable`
or
`cat file.csv | grep -Ev $variable`
Note, though, in your example,  the cat is not required:
`grep -Ev "${variable}" file.csv`
Notice the quotes around the variable, you may need those as well, depending on your shell & Linux version.

egrep (or grep -E) is an grep with Extended Regular Expression. The vertical bar, or pipe `|` separates the values. Effectively it is saying OR. Thus, 
`egrep -Ev "A|B"` means look for 'A' or 'B' and remove them.

Comment: Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Use `grep -E` so you can use an extended regular expression, and then use `|` in the regexp to match multiple strings.

```
variable=RESERVATIONS|N2_CPUS
grep -v -E "$variable" file.csv
```